# hyperledger fabric can we intergrate existing database into a blockchain network and how?

Tags: database, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, ibm-blockchain

i am trying to learn how to work with hyperledeger fabric but i have a lot of question that i couldn't  find a answer for
how is hyperledger fabric is implemented in organization and not just locally?
and can we integrate existing database into a blockchain network and how?
for example a databases can we integrate existing database into a blockchain network and how?
with users and their record is this possible?
i hope someone could answer me.

i have tried to read the documentations

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.